# how to write select query inside count function using mysql

Tags: mysql

i have 3 queries which actually counts the number of rows 
as folows

```
 select  count(*) from mydb.ISEVAENQUIRY where dated=15/12/2017 group by dated;

select  count(*) from mydb.ISEVAENQUIRY where dated=15/12/2017 and interested='yes' group by dated

select  count(*) from mydb.ISEVAENQUIRY where dated=15/12/2017 and closed='yes' group by dated;
```

i want to fire `three queries at time` how to do it?

how to combine them in one query? please help me.

Comment: I think you need three queries as you are asking for three distinct numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mysql only you can use following to get your count

```
select  sum(dated='15/12/2017') total,
sum(dated='15/12/2017' and interested='yes') total_interested,
sum(dated='15/12/2017' and closed='yes') total_closed
from mydb.ISEVAENQUIRY 
group by dated;
```

When `sum` is used with expression it will result as a boolean 0/1, So this way you can get your conditional count

Answer (score -1):

Look in the mySQL Manual for 'UNION' and 'UNION ALL', that should do the trick ;)
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: this is supposed to be comment not an answer